# setting a variable in Tcl as value returned by perl

Tags: perl, tcl

I am trying to use following command but it is not working:

```
set t1 [exec perl check.pl report.txt 5]
```

the perl file check.pl extracts 5 values from report.txt and returns.
check.pl has return in subrountine.

t1 is empty. value is not returned and not set.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What exactly is "not working" about it? Is there an error? no output? what happens when you run that perl command from the shell prompt?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in your check.pl, you'd want it to `print` the extracted values in order to have the values returned from Tcl `exec`:

> If standard output has not been redirected then the exec command returns the standard output from the last command in the pipeline, unless “2>@1” was specified, in which case standard error is included as well. ([exec manual page - Tcl Built-In Commands](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm))

For example, in `tclsh`:

```
% set foo [exec perl -e "print 'foobar\n'"]
foobar
% puts $foo
foobar
```

And for further parsing the output as a Tcl list you might want to `split` by the newline character (if the extracted values are printed each on their own line):

```
% set foolist [split [exec perl -e "print 'foo\nbar\n'"] "\n"]
foo bar
% llength $foolist
2
% lindex $foolist 1
bar
```